# ¿Cómo actualizar weld 3.0.5 en JBoss EAP 7.2?

Tags: java, jboss, actualizacion

Tengo un proyecto que está desarrollado con Java 11 y JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001)
Con la recién salida de Java 17 me han solicitado la actualización de Java 11 a Java 17 y manteniendo la versión de JBoss 7.2 pero estoy obteniendo el siguiente error.

```
    jboss.deployment.unit."proyecto.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1730)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1558)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-001524: Unable to load proxy class for bean Built-in Bean [javax.transaction.UserTransaction] with qualifiers [@Default] with class interface javax.transaction.UserTransaction using classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.weld.core" version 3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001 from local module loader @2e385cce (finder: local module finder @2ddc9a9f (roots: \jboss-eap-7.2\modules,\jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base))
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:370)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.run(ProxyFactory.java:324)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:316)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.ee.AbstractEEBean.<init>(AbstractEEBean.java:36)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.jta.UserTransactionBean.<init>(UserTransactionBean.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.jta.WeldTransactionsModule.preBeanRegistration(WeldTransactionsModule.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.module.WeldModules.preBeanRegistration(WeldModules.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:432)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:86)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:96)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1738)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1700)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1.run(ClassFile.java:394)
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1.run(ClassFile.java:385)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile.<clinit>(ClassFile.java:385)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.newClassFile(ProxyFactory.java:476)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.createProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:436)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:362)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: override
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2610)
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter@1.2.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile$1.run(ClassFile.java:392)
```

Estuve investigando y encontré que actualizando la versión del weld de la 3.0.5 a la 3.1.1 se soluciona el problema pero ahora obtento otro error.

Los directorios y bibliotecas y module.xml actualizados son los siguientes:

```
*jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\weld\core\main*

weld-web-3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar -> weld-web-3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar
weld-jta-3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar -> weld-jta-3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar
weld-ejb-3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar -> weld-ejb-3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar
weld-core-impl-3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar -> weld-core-impl-3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar

*jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\weld\probe\main*

weld-probe-core-3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar -> weld-probe-core-3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar

*jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\msc\main*

jboss-msc-1.4.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar -> jboss-msc-1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001.jar

*jboss-eap-7.2\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\jsf-injection\main*

weld-jsf-3.0.5.Final-redhat-00001.jar -> weld-jsf-3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001.jar
```

Sin embargo aún después de hacer esta actualización ahora obtengo el error:

```
00:55:40,788 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEE0007: No se está instalando el componente opcional mx.ine.evalSEyCAE.seguridad.ServletCaptcha debido a una excepción (active el nivel de registro DEBUG para ver la razón)
00:55:40,833 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 3.1.1 (redhat)
00:55:40,907 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."evalSEyCAE.war".WeldBootstrapService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."evalSEyCAE.war".WeldBootstrapService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.jboss.weld.serialization.spi.ProxyServices.supportsClassDefining()'
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startContainer(WeldStartup.java:218)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.1.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startContainer(WeldBootstrap.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.weld.WeldBootstrapService.start(WeldBootstrapService.java:129)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc@1.4.11.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    ... 6 more
```

Entiendo que no encuentra el método pero ¿Alguien tiene idea de qué me puede estar faltando o cómo se podría solucionar este error?.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No es possible executar EAP 7.2 con Java 17. Tienes que seguir la version de EAP (7.4). Pero esta version no puede executar on 17 tambien, pero se puede en el futuro.

Answer (score 1):

JBooss EAP al ser un servidor de entorno empresarial se tiene que probar exhaustivamente antes de aprobar la compatibilidad con las nuevas versiones Java para evitar cualquier problema con lo clientes que tienen grandes proyectos y prefieren ir sobre tecnología ya probada aunque no se la más puntera, además RedHat ya anuncio que el soporte de Java 17 sera para EAP 8, si quieres ir actualizando constantemente tienes que utilizar Wildfly que siempre estará al día porque lo que se prueba en Wildfly después de pasa JBoss EAP.